# How to load object in pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to load a pickled dictionary but keep getting attribute error such as this

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'
```

Below is the code to read and write pickle object. I am dumping pickled object on a linux workstation with python 2.7.12. The data is transferred to Mac with python 3.6.4, where readTrueData() is executed resulting in the above error.

```
def readTrueData(name):
    fName = str('trueData/'+name+'.pkl')
    f = open(fName,'rb')
    #    print(f)
    #    print(type(f))
    pC = pickle.loads(f)
    return pC

def storeTrueData(atomicConfigs, name):
    import quippy
    storeDic = {}
    #rangeKeys = len(atomicConfigs)
    #print(rangeKeys)
    qTrain = quippy.AtomsList(atomicConfigs)
    print(len(qTrain))
    rangeKeys = len(qTrain)
    print(rangeKeys)
    for i in range(rangeKeys):
        #configConsidered = atomicConfigs[i]
        trueForce = np.array(qTrain[i].force).T
        storeDic[i] = trueForce
    f = open("trueData/"+ name + ".pkl", "wb")
    pickle.dump(storeDic, f)
    f.close()    
    return None
```

## UPDATE

Working on the suggestions mentioned in the comments, I changed my code as below
a.)`pC = pickle.load(f)`
b.) `pC = pickle.loads(f.read())`
In both the case I got the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is caused by a mismatch between the argument type and the chosen `load*` method; `loads` expects `bytes` objects, `load` expects the file object itself. Passing the file object to `loads` is what caused your error.

Your other problem is due to the cross-version compatibility issue with `numpy` and `datetime` types; Python 2 pickles `str`s with no specified encoding, but Python 3 must unpickle them with a known encoding (or `'bytes'`, to get raw `bytes` rather than `str`). For `numpy` and `datetime` types, [you're required to pass `encoding='latin-1'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load):

> Optional keyword arguments are fix_imports, encoding and errors, which are used to control compatibility support for pickle stream generated by Python 2. If fix_imports is true, pickle will try to map the old Python 2 names to the new names used in Python 3. The encoding and errors tell pickle how to decode 8-bit string instances pickled by Python 2; these default to ‘ASCII’ and ‘strict’, respectively. The encoding can be ‘bytes’ to read these 8-bit string instances as bytes objects. Using encoding='latin1' is required for unpickling NumPy arrays and instances of datetime, date and time pickled by Python 2.

In any event, the fix is to change:

```
def readTrueData(name):
    fName = str('trueData/'+name+'.pkl')
    f = open(fName,'rb')
    #    print(f)
    #    print(type(f))
    pC = pickle.loads(f)
    return pC
```

to:

```
def readTrueData(name):
    fName = str('trueData/'+name+'.pkl')
    with open(fName, 'rb') as f:  # with statement avoids file leak
        # Match load with file object, and provide encoding for Py2 str
        return pickle.load(f, encoding='latin-1')
```

For correctness and performance reasons, I'd also recommend changing `pickle.dump(storeDic, f)` to `pickle.dump(storeDic, f, protocol=2)` on the Python 2 machine, so the stream is generated with a more modern pickle protocol, one which can efficiently pickle `numpy` arrays among other things. Protocol 0, the Python 2 default, can't use the top bit of each byte (it's ASCII compatible), which means raw binary data bloats dramatically in protocol 0, requiring a ton of bit twiddling, where protocol 2 can dump it raw. Protocol 2 is also the only Py2 protocol that efficiently pickles new style classes, and the only one that can properly pickle certain types of instances (stuff using `__slots__`/`__new__` and the like) at all.

I'd also recommend the script begin with:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle
```

as on Python 2, `pickle` is implemented in pure Python, and is both slow and unable to use some of the more efficient pickle codes. On Python 3, `cPickle` is gone, but `pickle` is automatically accelerated. Between that and using protocol 2, pickling on the Python 2 machine should run *much* faster, and produce *much* smaller pickles.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using `pickle.load(...)` to read if using `open` in that manner.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: It's not about matching `load` with `dump` and `loads` with `dumps`. It's about matching `load`/`dump` with open files, and `loads/`dumps` with in-memory use of `bytes` objects.

Comment: changed the code to pickle.load(f). Got the following error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 2):

`pC = pickle.loads(f.read())` is what you're looking for, but you should really be using the [`with` context](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with):

```
with open(fName, 'rb') as f: 
    pC = pickle.loads(f.read())
```

This would ensure your file is closed properly, especially because your code doesn't have a `f.close()` in the function.

Comment: chaged my code as per your suggestion. got the following error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: More efficiently, just do `pC = pickle.load(f)`, which avoids a large temporary buffer (`loads` is implemented by shoving the argument into `io.BytesIO` and then using `load` anyway, so using `load` directly reduces memory and CPU requirements).

Comment: @user1443613: Are you *sure* you matched their code? That error looks like what you'd get from opening a binary file for read in text mode (`'r'`/`'rt'`) when pickle files should always be opened in binary mode (`'rb'`). The alternative is that you are unpickling data from Python 2, and you need to pass the `encoding` argument to `load`/`loads` to specify what the assumed encoding of Python 2 `str`s should be (if you have no idea, `latin-1` is a decent default, and, per the docs, necessary for unpickling `numpy` and `datetime` types pickled on Python 2).

Comment: Thanks... it was encoding causing the problems. Inputting encoding = 'latin-1' solved it